# How to serialize Typescript type information?

Tags: typescript

I have a `ContentGateway` interface which looks like this:

```
interface ContentGateway {
    register: (eventType: EventType) => E.Either<Error, void>;
    send: <T> (event: T) => E.Either<Error, void>;
}
```

This works in a way that first you have to register an event, then you can start sending it.

I encoded the type information like this:

```
enum FieldType {
    STRING,
    BOOLEAN,
    NUMBER
}

type Field ={
    namespace: string;
    name: string;
    type: FieldType;
}


type EventType = {
    version: string;
    name: string;
    fields: Field[];
}
```

This is not ideal, because ideally how this would look like is something like this:

```
interface ContentGateway {
    register: <T> (eventType: T) => E.Either<Error, void>;
    send: <T> (event: T) => E.Either<Error, void>;
}
```

The problem is that there is a process barrier between the caller and the callee (usually a REST interface) so I need to serialize the type information.

Is there a way to serialize Typescript type information if I know in advance that both sides will use Typescript?

I know about [io-ts](https://github.com/gcanti/io-ts/blob/master/index.md):

```
import * as t from 'io-ts'

const User = t.type({
  userId: t.number,
  name: t.string
})
```

but it only supports a TypeOf operation:

```
type User = t.TypeOf<typeof User>

// same as
type User = {
  userId: number
  name: string
}
```

not the other way around.

**Edit:** I'm aware that Typescript types dont' exist at runtime, but `io-ts` `Type` objects can be serialized. The above example for example will look like this when I send it over the wire:

```json
{
   "name":"User",
   "props":{
      "id":{
         "name":"number",
         "_tag":"NumberType"
      },
      "name":{
         "name":"string",
         "_tag":"StringType"
      }
   },
   "_tag":"InterfaceType"
}
```

So the question is how to restore the `Type` object from this json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Restoring `t.Type` instance from the object serialization

The approach I've used in the past for something similar is to reflect on the tag names to walk arbitrary type information.

```js
import { absurd, pipe } from "fp-ts/lib/function";
import * as E from "fp-ts/lib/Either";
import * as R from "fp-ts/lib/ReadonlyRecord";
import * as t from "io-ts";

const InterfaceMetaCodec = t.type({
  _tag: t.literal("InterfaceType"),
  props: t.UnknownRecord
});

const ArrayMetaCodec = t.type({
  _tag: t.literal("ArrayType"),
  type: t.unknown
});

const UnionMetaCodec = t.type({
  _tag: t.literal("UnionType"),
  types: t.UnknownArray
});

const IntersectionMetaCodec = t.type({
  _tag: t.literal("IntersectionType"),
  types: t.UnknownArray
});

const makeSimpleMetaCodec = <T extends string>(tag: T) =>
  t.type({
    _tag: t.literal(tag)
  });

const NullMetaCodec = makeSimpleMetaCodec("NullType");
const UndefinedMetaCodec = makeSimpleMetaCodec("UndefinedType");
const VoidMetaCodec = makeSimpleMetaCodec("VoidType");
const BooleanMetaCodec = makeSimpleMetaCodec("BooleanType");
const NumberMetaCodec = makeSimpleMetaCodec("NumberType");
const StringMetaCodec = makeSimpleMetaCodec("StringType");
const AnyMetaCodec = makeSimpleMetaCodec("AnyType");
const UnknownMetaCodec = makeSimpleMetaCodec("UnknownType");

const LiteralMetaCodec = t.type({
  _tag: t.literal("LiteralType"),
  value: t.union([t.number, t.string, t.boolean])
});

const MetaCodec = t.union([
  NullMetaCodec,
  UndefinedMetaCodec,
  VoidMetaCodec,
  BooleanMetaCodec,
  NumberMetaCodec,
  StringMetaCodec,
  IntersectionMetaCodec,
  UnionMetaCodec,
  InterfaceMetaCodec,
  LiteralMetaCodec,
  AnyMetaCodec,
  UnknownMetaCodec,
  ArrayMetaCodec
]);

const sequenceRecord = R.sequence(E.either);

const recursivelyDecode = (type: unknown): E.Either<t.Errors, t.Mixed> =>
  pipe(
    type,
    MetaCodec.decode,
    E.chain((cursor) => {
      switch (cursor._tag) {
        case "InterfaceType": {
          return pipe(
            Object.fromEntries(
              Object.entries(cursor.props).map(
                ([key, p]) => [key, recursivelyDecode(p)] as const
              )
            ),
            sequenceRecord,
            E.map((props) => t.type(props))
          );
        }
        case "UnionType": {
          return pipe(
            cursor.types.map(recursivelyDecode),
            E.sequenceArray,
            E.map((ts) => t.union(ts as [t.Mixed, t.Mixed, ...t.Mixed[]]))
          );
        }
        case "IntersectionType": {
          return pipe(
            cursor.types.map(recursivelyDecode),
            E.sequenceArray,
            E.map((ts) => t.intersection(ts as [t.Mixed, t.Mixed]))
          );
        }
        case "ArrayType": {
          return pipe(
            recursivelyDecode(cursor.type),
            E.map((aT) => t.array(aT))
          );
        }
        case "LiteralType": {
          return E.right(t.literal(cursor.value));
        }
        case "StringType": {
          return E.right(t.string);
        }
        case "BooleanType": {
          return E.right(t.boolean);
        }
        case "NumberType": {
          return E.right(t.number);
        }
        case "NullType": {
          return E.right(t.null);
        }
        case "UndefinedType": {
          return E.right(t.undefined);
        }
        case "VoidType": {
          return E.right(t.void);
        }
        case "AnyType": {
          return E.right(t.any);
        }
        case "UnknownType": {
          return E.right(t.unknown);
        }
        default: {
          return absurd(cursor);
        }
      }
    })
  );
```

You can use this to decode arbitrary types from the serialization you decribed. Once you have validated a type, you will have a runtime instance of an `io-ts` class so you can then use it to validate incoming data. At compile time, every value that is decoded from a codec that was decoded at runtime using the recursive walker code will be `any`, so you can't benefit from static type checking but you can still rely on the validation.

That's a bit wordy but I just mean that the value returned by `runtimeCodec.decode(someThing)` will be `Either<t.Errors, any>` in the following example.

A validation from one of these decoded codecs just asserts that the data is in the shape specified but you can't know anything about the shape of that data at compile time.

```js
const someType: unknown = t.type({
  a: t.string,
  b: t.type({
    foo: t.unknown
  }),
  c: t.union([t.undefined, t.literal("cat")])
});

console.log(recursivelyDecode(someType));

const assertRight = <E, T>(e: E.Either<E, T>): T => {
  if (E.isLeft(e)) {
    throw new Error("Failed to decode");
  }
  return e.right;
};
const runtimeCodec = assertRight(recursivelyDecode(someType));
const someThing: unknown = {
  a: "123",
  b: {
    foo: new Date()
  },
  c: undefined
};

console.log(runtimeCodec.decode(someThing));
```

Note, I did not add a case for `RecursiveType` as I think that might be a little bit more involved. It may be possible though? Also note that you'll need to add cases for any custom types you've created and those types will need a unique `_tag` property to be handled correctly in the `switch`. I'm also using `Object.fromEntries` and `Object.entries` which you might need to update your `"lib"` configuration to support. (There are polyfills for both methods available).

I hope this is helpful. If you want actual types at compile time, you will need to instead do some sort of code generation from the serialized codecs.

### Edit Follow Up:

[There is a ticket](https://github.com/gcanti/io-ts/issues/412) for adding better support for serialization of recursive types which is still open at the time of writing.

There is also [this ticket](https://github.com/gcanti/io-ts/issues/197) for adding more general support for serialization of type schemas. Once these go out, it will expand the ease with which you can tackle your problem.

Comment: This is a great answer, thank you! I also bumped into the type information problem so I ended up creating an `nx` monorepo and I shared the code that describes the subset of *JSON Schema* I intend to support.